# How should I include MVC related namespaces in a nuget package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I would like to create a nuget package to import a library of MVC-ish stuff into an MVC project.  For example:

- models
- enums
- attributes

But I am confused as to how I should be including their namespaces.

After creating a new Class Library, I try to use the namespace `System.ComponentModels.DataAnnotations`, but it is not recognised.

I have tried using the `References` section in Solution Explorer. But there appears to be no option there - only the message:

`No recent framework assemblies were found on your machine or in your project.json`.

[image]

Ok, so I go to the `project.json` file.

But I am unsure how I should be adding these references here.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ClassLibrary1 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "MHL" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.0.0",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0.0",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.0.0",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.0.0",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0.0",
    "System.ComponentModel.DataAnotations":  "4.0.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
}
```

If I add `"System.ComponentModel.DataAnotations":  "4.0.0.0"` to the `dependencies` section, I get the build error `Dependency could not be resolved`.

So I ***think*** I should be changing something in the `frameworks` section.

But I am unsure what to add, not least because there are so many options (e.g. "dotnet", "net40", "net50", "dnx", etc)!

My understanding is that the `frameworks` section enables a single nuget package to target different framework versions.  But really, all I want is a general purpose MVC package.   I don't want to unnecessarily limit the package to a specific version of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to NugetPackage manager for solution.

Search and add `ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

[image]

Be sure to rebuild your solution.

You will find it recognises the using and it appears in your references on the side.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @MrsEd, and for the screenshots, they've really helpful. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but I will do over the next couple of days.

Comment: All looks good - thanks very much for the votes and for solving my problem. :)